# How to use the current date as name for a CSV file

Tags: matlab, mat, scilab

How do I create a csv file with date as the name of the csv file. I tried doing it, but the date won't appear only the name does. The language is Scilab which is similar to Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your question fully. But following the [csvWrite](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/csvWrite.html) documentation and the [date](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/date.html) documentation. You could do someting like this

```
filename_with_date_string = date() + ".csv";
directory_path = TMPDIR;

// Some matrix you want to save
M = [1:10] * 0.1;     

// Create the file
file = fullfile(directory_path, filename_with_date_string);

// Fill it with your matrix
csvWrite(M, file);
```