# I am trying to copy a file and have the current date

Tags: scilab

I am using scilab and I have a file I want to copy and backup. The copied file should have the date when it was copied on its name e.g 'Read.dat' to become 'Read_12-April-2014.dat'. I only manage to copy the file but the date does not appear.

```
copyfile('Read.dat','Archive/Read_'dt=date()'.dat')
```

Comment: And the code you have tried?

Comment: copyfile('Read.dat','Archive/Read_'dt=date()'.dat')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems related tot [How to use the current date as name for a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22668855/1149326).

```
src_name_string = 'Read.dat';
dst_name_string  = 'Archive/Read_' + date() + '.dat';

copyfile(src_name_string, dst_name_string);
```